# While using JRXlsxExporter, the file is not getting generated with proper extension

Tags: jasper-reports, xlsx

I am trying to generate the report in .xlsx format and for that I have written this code:

```
                fileExtension = ".xlsx";
                file = this.getTempFileOutput(xnetMetaDB, fileExtension);
                JRXlsxExporter exporter = new JRXlsxExporter();
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
                exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE, file);
                exporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET,Boolean.FALSE);
                exporter.exportReport();
```

when I am trying to preview the report a popup appears with 'open', 'save' or 'save as' options, if i click on save the file's extension is not .xlsx and the file is unreadable. Also if i select 'save as' even then I have to specifically append the .xlsx extension to file name.
I want that if someone select save or save as options then the file should get automatically saved with .xlsx extension.
Please help me with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer for my question. This issue was occurring because in the web.xml file the mime mapping for "xlsx" format was missing.

xlsx
        application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

 I did this and it worked.